# Windows 7: Use VirtualStore technology as user for own benefit?

Tags: windows-7, uac

I've researched a bit and came to the understanding that VirtualStore is part of the new UAC feature in Vista/W7 which is the file system part of the transparent data redirection and redirects write access to folders like `program files` to `C:\User\<username>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\` in lack of applications respecting the [LUA principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_user_access).

Now I'm interested if that kind of transparent redirection can also be used as a power to the user. Here's an example which comes to my mind:

I install any kind of software to e.g. `D:\Whatever\ThisAndThisApp\` and I set up things that, after initial installation, any write access to this folder is transparently redirected to e.g. `D:\MyOwnVirtualStore\Whatever\ThisAndThisApp\file_only_writable_here.txt`.

Is this thinking too far or can I actually use that power of VirtualStore as a user on Windows 7? I'm using the Professional version zf that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can't, and in any case the Virtual Store is hardwired to be the folder
`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\VirtualStore`.

The only mechanism available to users are [Symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), which under Windows 7 are known as [Hard Links and Junctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365006%28VS.85%29.aspx).

If that's something you would like to use, you will find the program [Hard Link Magic](http://www.brothersoft.com/hard-link-magic-14448.html) to be useful.

Comment: Symbolic links are soft lonks and are *different* to hard links. Windows 7 includes the `mklink` tool to handle links. Junctions are effectively symbolic links which point to a directory rather than a file. As mklink allows one to make symbolic links to a directory they seem rather pointless.

Comment: Accepting, as it seems what I'm asking for is currently not possible.